# Filter api data in Angular 6 service

Tags: angular, typescript

All the examples still refer to Angular 2 methods and NG6 uses pipe for data calls within a service.

This basic method in my service gets all of the data returned by the API:

```
  getPatchGroups(): Observable<PatchGroup[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
      .pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Now, I need to split this up so that I have a call that returns anything with an id of -1 and a call that gets everything else.  I need to display the two groups of data in different areas of the page.

```
  getUngroupedPatchGroups(): Observable<PatchGroup[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
      .pipe(
        map(this.extractData),  // where id < 0
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getGroupedPatchGroups(): Observable<PatchGroup[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
      .pipe(
        map(this.extractData),  // where id > 0
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

It feels dirty to filter in the component but that would be one way... create a custom pipe and apply to the ngFor.  Would performance, etc. be better to create two functions and apply a filter to each?  What is the correct format for NG 6.1.1?

EDIT
If I add the filter to the extraData I get the results I expect.  However, Response is deprecated and body is shadow named?  How do I fix this?

```
  private extractData(resp: Response) {
    const body = resp.json();
    return body.filter(body => body.id > 0);
  }
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/partition.html

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Interesting information, but I still cannot figure out how to react based upon a value in one of the columns of data of a row being returned.  The API returns a record with 7 properties, how do I react based on the value of one of those properties?  The examples all seem to show the record only have a single property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having just one API call and return object?

```
getPatchGroups(): Observable<{less: PatchGroup[], more: PatchGroup[]}> {
return this.http
  .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
       const jsonData = data.json();
       return {less: jsonData.filter(d => d.id < 0), more: jsonData.filter(d => d.id > 0)};
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Edit: And in the component, based on code posted to comment you seem to rename `more` and `less` to `grouped` and `ungrouped`:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.appsApiService.getPatchGroups().subscribe(pg => {
     this.ungrouped_patchGroups = pg.ungrouped;
     this.grouped_patchGroups = pg.grouped;
 });
```

Alternatively have 2 subjects in the service for "less" and "more", update them in `tap` or rather `subscribe` after API call and listen to observables created from those SubjectS.

Comment: Hmm, this looks promising, but need to adjust data.filter to data.json().filter.

Comment: Modified the answer for you, HTH

Comment: Unable to assign the second one, shows as type any instead of strongly typed.  `  ngOnInit() {
    this.appsApiService.getPatchGroups()
      .subscribe(pg => this.ungrouped_patchGroups = pg.ungrouped,
        pg => this.grouped_patchGroups = pg.grouped);
  }
`

Comment: Modified once again

Answer (score 0):

Without having a clear view of your data structure and application, this becomes difficult to answer. Based on your question and comment, I would assume you would need something like the following:

```
return this.http
           .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
           .pipe(
             partition(patchGroup => patchGroup.id > 0),  // where id > 0
             catchError(this.handleError)
           );
```

The partition method takes a predicate, which is a function that is applied to every item in the iterable.